# Three.js: Page moves down when clicking on object

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, web-testing

This is my first time adding Three.js and I just want to include in a landing page of my website.
I have a problem whenever I click on the area of the scene where my object is, the page moves down. What can I do to prevent this from happening? It looks like when I click on it, the page moves so the object is in the center. I tried to add overflow: hidden; in my css but that doesn't work. I am suspecting I have to change something in the javascript code.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 8;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
scene.add(ambientLight);
light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 20);
light.position.set(10,10,10);
light.castShadow = true; 
light.shadow.camera.near = 10;
light.shadow.camera.far = 25; 
scene.add(light);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);




var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.enablePan = false;

var boxGeom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(3, 3, 3, 33, 33, 33);


// this is the shortened part from the official example to create the sphere morph targets
var pos = boxGeom.attributes.position;
boxGeom.morphAttributes.position = [];
var spherePositions = [];
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
for (var i = 0; i < pos.count; i++) {
  v3.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i).setLength((1.5 * Math.sqrt(1.5) + 1.5) * 0.6);
  spherePositions.push(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
}
boxGeom.morphAttributes.position[0] = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(spherePositions, 3);

var boxMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: "white",
  wireframe: false,
  flatShading: true,
  morphTargets: true
});
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, boxMat);
scene.add(box);


// user's custom properties and methods
box.userData.isHovering = true;
box.userData.currentAction = null;
box.userData.toSphere = () => {
  action(1);
}
box.userData.toBox = () => {
  action(0);
}

// tweening function
function action(influence) {

  if (box.userData.currentAction) box.userData.currentAction.stop();
  
  box.userData.currentAction = new TWEEN.Tween(box.morphTargetInfluences).to({
    "0": influence
  }, 1000).start();
  
}

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

function onMouseMove(event) {

  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(box);
  
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
  
    if (!box.userData.isHovering) {
    
      box.userData.toSphere();
      box.userData.isHovering = true;
      
    };
  } else {
  
    if (box.userData.isHovering) {
    
      box.userData.toBox();
      box.userData.isHovering = false;
      
    }
  }
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

  TWEEN.update();
 box.rotation.x += 0.01;
 box.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  
});



 window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

 function onWindowResize() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }
```

```css
/*font*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'coresansgs55mediuuploadedfile';
    src: url('../fonts/core_sans_gs_55_medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/core_sans_gs_55_medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');


/*background*/
body {
    
    margin: 0;
    user-select: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF76FB 0%, #C57BFF 35%, #00FFFB 100%);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    animation: BackgroundGradient 20s ease infinite; 
    
    
    ::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
    
}


@keyframes BackgroundGradient {
                0% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
                50% {background-position: 100% 50%;}
                100% {background-position: 0% 50%;}
}


/*content*/

h1 {    font-family: 'coresansgs55mediuuploadedfile';
        font-size: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 50px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: 1;
        }
    
h1 a{color: #00FFD8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px blue;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px blue, 0px 0px blue, 3px 3px blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;}

h1 a:hover {color: #febfff;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px magenta;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px magenta, 0px 0px magenta, 5px 4px magenta; 
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;}
    

    

ul {
-webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
    
}

li {
  display: inline;
    }    
    
li a {
    padding: 20px 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'coresansgs55mediuuploadedfile';
    font-size: 30px;
    color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    
}
    
li a:hover{
  color: magenta;
}

.changing-title {
    position: fixed;
    top: 640px;
    text-align: center;
    
    
    
}

.changing-keyword {
    user-select: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 38px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s;
  visibility: collapse;
  position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.shown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (min-width: 2000px) {
    .changing-title {
    position: relative;
    top: 640px;
    right: 50%;
        text-align: center;}
        
    .changing-keyword {
    font-size: 50px;
  
    }}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        
        
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">

                <h1>
            <a href="../MAIN/main.html">hello world</a> 
        </h1>
        
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <ul>
  <li><a href="../WORK/work.html">work</a></li>
  <li><a href="../ABOUT/about.html">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CONTACT/contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        

        

        

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.4.0/Tween.min.js"></script>

        <script src="../MAIN/main.js"></script>

        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like OrbitControls places a mousedown event listener on the canvas and calls the canvas into focus. You'll need to remove/override that event listener to prevent the focus behavior.

[Here's a screenshot from devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyywR.png)

Comment: ahh because i left <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> in my HTML from another thing I was trying, I forgot to delete it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Overriding/deleting the mousedown function might break other features.

So instead just use this line of code:

```
controls.domElement.focus = null;
```

This will stop the focus to window or domElement.

Thanks to @hayden-linder who puts our focus to dig more into it.